# How to pass lexical bindings of functions to 'eval' in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp, eval

In Emacs Lisp, lexical environment are represented by an alist, mapping symbols to their value.  It can be passed to evaluators as a second argument of 'eval' function.

```
(eval '(+ 3 var)
      '((var . 4)))
→ 7
```

However, I can't figure out how to pass functions, not variables,
to the evaluator.

For example, either of the following expressions shows an error.

```
 (eval '(func 3)
       '((func . (lambda (x) (+ 4 x)))))
 → error: (void-function func)
 (eval '(func 3)
       '((func . (closure (t) (x) (+ 4 x)))))
 → error: (void-function func)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Emacs Lisp is a [Lisp-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LISP_2), not a [Lisp-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LISP_1).

Answer (score 1):

How about this :

```
(eval '(apply func (list 3))
       '((func . (lambda (x) (+ 4 x)))))
```

Comment: I'm sorry, that will restrict the function to be applied only once and the first., and that is not what I wanted.

How about, say, the expression is something like:

    '(+ (func (func (func 3))) 4)

?

Comment: No, there is no such restriction: you can do `(+ (funcall func (funcall func (funcall func 3))) 4)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it:

```
(defun my-eval (exp var-bindings fun-bindings)
  (eval `(cl-flet ,(mapcar (lambda (x) (list (car x) `',(cdr x)))
                           fun-bindings)
           (let ,(mapcar (lambda (x) (list (car x) `',(cdr x)))
                         var-bindings)
             ,exp))
        t))
```

or, using `eval`'s builtin support for `var-bindings`:

```
(defun my-eval (exp var-bindings fun-bindings)
  (eval `(cl-flet ,(mapcar (lambda (x) (list (car x) `',(cdr x)))
                           fun-bindings)
           ,exp)
        (or var-bindings t)))
```

[ BTW, note that it is not always true that in Emacs Lisp, lexical environment are represented by an alist: after byte-compilation, lexical variables don't have any name any more, they're stored on "the" stack and they're directly accessed via their position in the stack.  ]

Comment: Thanks!  May I ask the question to further?
(I once considered the use of cl-flet / cl-label but couldn't solve the following problem.)

How about the function with closures whose symbols contains the values from outer lexical scope bindings?

For example, what I really wanted was something like

    (let ((a 4))
      (eval '(func 3)
               `((func . (closure ((b . ,a) t) (x) (+ x b))))))

to be evaluated as '7'.

Comment: You shouldn't write `(closure ...)` in your code because that's a value you want to build at run-time instead.  IOW instead of `'((func . (closure ((b . ,a) t) (x) (+ x b))))` write `\`((func . ,(lambda (x) (+ x b))))`.